# What is the meaning of []json.Rawmessage

Tags: arrays, go, structure, slice

What is the meaning of `[]json.Rawmessage`. Its within this structure here:

```
type Request struct {
    Jsonrpc string            `json:"jsonrpc"`
    Method  string            `json:"method"`
    Params  []json.RawMessage `json:"params"`
    ID      interface{}       `json:"id"`
}
```

I know its a slice of type json. I do not understand what the `.RawMessage` is referring to.  I tried looking it up in both golang tour and my golang book.  Also ultimately I know `Params` is type `[]json.Rawmessage` being bundled into another type called `Request`

Futhermore:

What is going on with these segments `json:"jsonrpc"`.  Is a string literal somehow being attached to var? Again this is not in golang tour or my golang book. Thanks for your time.

Comment: No, it's not a slice of type json. It's a slice of type `json.RawMessage`.

Answer (score 2):

[] is defining a slice

`json` is the package [import](https://thenewstack.io/understanding-golang-packages/) name (from your import statement above)

`RawMessage` is the [type](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/stream.go?s=6218:6240#L237) within the package. In this case for a []byte type.

`json:"params"` is a [field tag](https://flaviocopes.com/go-tags/). The json package reads it with reflection and determines what name to use for json.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time time you need to look in to the package doc rather than some book and the online tour.

The `json:"jsonrpc"` is a struct tag.
For this specific case the json.Marshal function will read that struct tag and return the JSON field name with the given value. For more about "encoding/json" struct tags usage: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

For RawMessage, you can read more about it here https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage 

`type RawMessage []byte`

Normally I use it when having a "generic" kind of JSON object that don't need to be process right the way (maybe I just send them to another service, or I will unmarshall it later depending on conditions). For example (I will use your `Request` struct):

```
jsonString := `[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "method": "getSomething",
    "params": [{"A": 1, "B": 2}]
  }
  {
    "id": 123,
    "method": "getSomethingElse",
    "params": [{"C": 1, "D": 2}]
  }
]`
```

With this processing code:

```
var requests []Request
json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &requests)
// if no error, you will have 2 items in requests
// requests[0].Params[0] is equal to []byte(`{"A": 1, "B": 2}`)
// requests[1].Params[0] is equal to []byte(`{"C": 1, "D": 2}`)

for _, req := range requests {
  if req.Method == "getSomething" {
    justProxyThisRequestToAnotherService(req)
  } else if req.Method == "getSomethingElse" {
    var params []map[string]int
    json.Unmarshal(req.Params, &params)
    // then do something with params
  }
}
```

Comment: Is '[]byte(jsonString)'  a slice of type jsonstring or is it the function byte() that is receiving jsonString and then returning a slice of those bytes?

Comment: the type of `jsonString` is just `string`, and `string` is an slice of byte. `[]byte(jsonString)` is the syntax for `type conversions` https://tour.golang.org/basics/13